# Open SQL Server MDF file in datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am new to Visual Basic and I am taking a Visual Basic class my last semester for fun. I am having trouble getting a datagridview to connect to a `.MDF` SQL Server database file my instructor gave me. I am getting a null exception error  on sConnection.ConnectionString ="" and I'm at a loss on this one.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    sConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jkome\Desktop\Kayaks.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
    sConnection.Open()

    sCommand.CommandText = "Select * from KayakTypes;"
    sReader = sCommand.ExecuteReader()
    sTable.Load(sReader)
    DGVkyaks.DataSource = sTable
```

Comment: Well, first of all: do you have SQL Server **Express** installed on your PC with the default settings (instance name of `SQLEXPRESS`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sTable As New DataTable
        Dim connectionString As String =
            <Text>
                Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jkome\Desktop\CustomerDatabase.mdf;
                Integrated Security=True;
                Connect Timeout=30
            </Text>.Value

        Using cn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = connectionString}
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand With
                {
                    .CommandText = "Select * from KayakTypes",
                    .Connection = cn
                }

                cn.Open()
                sTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

            End Using
        End Using

        DGVkyaks.DataSource = sTable

    End Sub
End Class
```